# Preprocess an array for counting an element in a slice (reduction to RMQ?)

Tags: algorithms, arrays, algorithm-design

Given an array $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ of natural numbers $\leq k$, where $k$ is a constant, I want to answer in $O(1)$ queries of the form: "how many times does $m$ appear in the array between indices $i$ and $j$"?

The array should be preprocessed in linear time. In particular I'd like to know if there's a reduction to Range Minimum Query.

---

This is equivalent to RMQ in the case where $k=1$ and you want to query the number of ones within an interval. So we can use [it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Queries#Statement_Of_The_Problem).
<sup>I couldn't answer my own question because of limits of SE.</sup>

Comment: You can reduce element distinctness to your problem (in linear time). Perhaps talking about a model is in order?

Comment: @Aryabhata what's exactly element distinctness problem?
Now I'm reading this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_Queries

Comment: This is much easier than RMQ.  Hint: Because k is a constant, preprocessing can spend time proportional to kn and it still counts as linear time.

Comment: @Aryabhata: The reduction which I think you are talking about does not work because k is a constant in this problem.

Comment: Just in case, if the array is given at the beginning and is not updated afterward, RMQ is an overkill, as I suggested in my earlier comment.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Yes you are right, I somehow missed that.

Comment: @andy: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem. My first comment applies if you didn't have that upper bound of $k$.

Comment: @andy, Feel free to [answer your own](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) question and [accept](http://cs.stackexchange.com/faq) it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $k$ is constant, we can store the count of each element in the range $0..m$  for $0\leq m \lt n$ in $0..n$ in $O(nk) = O(n)$ time and space. The primary observation is that you can make a two-dimensional array `count[pos][elem] = occurences of 'elem' in the indices 0..pos` in $O(nk)$ time, then query ranges by finding the difference in $i,j$ indices in constant time.

**Preprocessing**

```
initialise count[pos][elem] to 0 for all elem, pos
for pos=0 to n
  for num=0 to k
      count[pos][num] = (0 if pos==0 else count[pos-1][num])
  count[pos][arr[pos]] ++
```

**Query**

(assumes i,j are both inclusive bounds)

```
if i == 0
  return count[j][m]
else
  return count[j][m] - count[i-1][m]
```

If the array is also getting updated throughout the query process, you can use $k$ Fenwick (binary index) trees in place of the `count` array. This lets you update in $O(\log n)$ and query in $O(\log n)$.

Apologies for any issues with this answer, it's my first.